# Replacing data in xlsx sheet with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file with multiple tabs, one of them being `Town_names` that already has some data in it.

I'd like to overwrite that data with a dataframe - `Town_namesDF` - while keeping the rest of the xlsx tabs intact.

I've tried the following:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'path/to/file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    Town_namesDF.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Town_names')
    writer.save()

writer.close()
```

But it ends up creating a new tab `Town_names1` instead of overwriting the `Town_names` tab. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've managed to do this. This is not a clean solution and not fast at all, but I've made  use of openpyxl documentation for working with pandas found here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

I'm effectively selecting the `Town_names` sheet, clearing it with `ws.delete_rows()` and then appending each row of my dataframe to the sheet.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path/to/file.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Town_names')
ws.delete_rows(0, 1000)

wb.save(r'path/to/file.xlsx')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path/to/file.xlsx')
activeSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Town_names')

for r in dataframe_to_rows(Town_namesDF, index=False, header=True):
    activeSheet.append(r)

for cell in activeSheet['A'] + activeSheet[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

wb.save(r'path/to/file.xlsx')
```

A bit messy and I hope there's a better solution than mine, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to overwrite, but there is no direct option for that(like in julia's XLSX there is option for cell_ref). Simply delete the duplicate if it exists and then write.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('/path/to/file.xlsx',engine = "openpyxl",  mode='a') as writer:
 workBook = writer.book
 try:
  workBook.remove(workBook['Town_names'])
 except:
  print("worksheet doesn't exist")
 finally:
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Town_names')
 writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked fine and it was my strategy at first, but I kinda hoped there would be a way to do it without deleting the sheet as it can screw with the order when you're working with a lot of sheets.

Comment: amazing that this is the only solution i can find in all of stack overflow that actually properly replaces a single sheet, it's mind-boggling that such a simple operation needs to be so complicated rather than to just have some kind of "overwrite" flag

Answer (score 2):

since pandas version 1.3.0. there is a new parameter: "if_sheet_exists"
{‘error’, ‘new’, ‘replace’}

```py
pd.ExcelWriter(r'path/to/file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to store all of the other sheets temporarily and then add them back. I don't think this would save any formulas or formatting though.

```
Store_sheet1=pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')
Store_sheet2=pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet2')
Store_sheet3=pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet3')

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'path/to/file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    Town_namesDF.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Town_names')
    Store_sheet1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    Store_sheet2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
    Store_sheet3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet3')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I haven't tested your solution, mainly because I'm working with a lot of sheets that aren't always the same. Using your solution would've involved getting all the sheet names and storing them in a list of stored sheets and then using it to reorder them, which was starting to get a bit overly complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xlwings for that task. A requirement of xlwings is to have Microsoft Excel installed. Here is an example:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

path = r"test.xlsx"

df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

# The with block inserts df to an existing Excel worksheet, 
# in this case to the one with the name "Town_names".
with xw.App(visible=False):
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    ws = wb.sheets["Town_names"]

    ws.clear()
    ws["A1"].value = df

    # If formatting of column names and index is needed as xlsxwriter does it, the following lines will do it.
    ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Font.Bold = True
    ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Font.Bold = True
    ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Borders.Weight = 2
    ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Borders.Weight = 2

    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```