# Using python how to take input search string from one excel sheet column and search in other excel on a specific column?

Tags: python, excel

For example, take input string _TXT from col A in file 1 and search in file 2 col X. If any row contains _TXT, then for that specific row compare col B value to col Y value in file 1 to file 2.

If col B and col Y values matches, take no action. If they are not matched, update col Y in file 2 with same value as col B in file 1

[image: excel image click here]

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: See my answer for a working solution in python if performance is not a concern. However, it seems like you want to synchronize the contents of your two excel files and excel allows for references between different spreadsheets : is there a reason for which using a formula like '=vlookup("*"&X1, '[path/to/refFile.xslx]'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)' in column Y of your destination file does not work ?

Comment: Thank you @Betebizarre ,My file 1 will be checking for strings in different excel files not just file 2, for that purpose I am trying to do it in python

Answer (score 0):

A simple (though perhaps not the most efficient) way to do this would be to follow this algorithm :

- load both excel files into python memory ;
- for each row in input file, take inputString from colA and look for it in output dataFrame, perform operations as needed ;
- write back second file to disk.

Pandas offer a function to read an excel file ([read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)). There are quite a lot of options, documented in the link : I think the ones that would be useful to you are :

- sheet_name : defaults to 0 (first sheet), you can also use its full name (as a string) or any number (N would be N+1th sheet). None means "all_sheets".
- usecols : defaults to None (all columns), if you only need colA and colB you may want to specify that here (using something like "A:B") ;

The function to write back your pandas dataframe to excel is a method of the class DataFrame (full documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)) called to_excel. Useful options include :

- excel_writer : it can be a file path or an ExcelWriter object, which is a pandas class that writes dataframes to excel. Using an ExcelWriter allows you to control more precisely what you write and might be necessary if you have to write several sheets, or change your file in place ;
- sheet_name : defaults to "Sheet1", does not seem to accept integers for sheet numbers ;
- index : default to True, writes row index as well as other data - we don't want that, so it will be necessary to put it to false.

Your final code might look something like this :

```
from pandas import *

# read both excel files ; assume only one sheet in file to modify
# taking only useful columns in reference file according to your example
dfIn = read_excel("path/to/refFile.xlsx", usecols="A:B")
dfOut = read_excel("path/to/outFile.xlsx", usecols=None, sheet_name="data_sheet")

for index, rowIn in dfIn.iterrows():
    inputString = rowIn['colA']
    for index, rowOut in dfOut.iterrows():
        # using python string endswith as matching rule
        # replace with anything that suits your needs
        if rowOut['colX'].endswith(inputString):
            rowOut['colY'] = rowIn['colB']
# write dfOut to disk
with ExcelWriter("path/to/outFile.xlsx", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    dfOut.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="data_sheet", index=False)
```

Admittedly, the pandas documentation warns against modifying something you are iterating over (because iterrows might return a copy of the data instead of a view, and then changing the copy will have no effect). Since you are using strings here, the modifications will work.

Depending on your excel engine and its version (it worked for me with python 3.8.10 and openpyxl 3.0.9, but failed for OP) replacing the sheet might fail. If that is the case, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326076/replacing-data-in-xlsx-sheet-with-pandas-dataframe) suggests completely deleting the old sheet and making a new one, like this :

```
with ExcelWriter('/path/to/file.xlsx',engine = "openpyxl",  mode='a') as writer:
 workBook = writer.book
 # data_sheet exists for sure, since we read data from it at beginning of script
 workBook.remove(['data_sheet'])
 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data_sheet', index=False)
 writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for above inputs, I have also added engine="openpyxl" in ExcelWriter to handle the waring,  The logic is working as expected when i use print , but the File 2 excel columns are not updated . Can you please advise if am missing ang thing else

Comment: If the logic works correctly using print, it is very likely that something is wrong in the part were you write to disk. 
  Does the program terminate correctly or raise an error ?
  Have you checked your output excel sheet for other sheets with the updated data ?
  Are you sure about the path to your data sheet ?

If those checks are unsuccessful, can you provide the part of your code that should write the data to the disk so we can look into it ?

Comment: Program didn't raise any error. Yes I have checked output excel file, a new sheet was added as data_sheet1 whole sheet as in data_sheet without any updates. I want the updates to be made in same sheet “data_sheet” tab.
<code>with ExcelWriter("path/to/outFile.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    dfOut.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="data_sheet", index=False)</code>

Comment: It looks like openpyxl is the default on my system too. Maybe it's something version-dependent - It seems like a similar problem was raised in other places. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326076/replacing-data-in-xlsx-sheet-with-pandas-dataframe is a related question and suggests manually deleting before writing your dataframe using your writer. Might update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you @Betebizarre it is working with deleting existing sheet and replacing it. But header formats and all will be lost if I create a new sheet . I think it is not possible to update existing sheet using python without deleting it.